# Tengo problemas al enviar mis credenciales y consumir una API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api

Ya logre resolver mi duda sobre el token, ahora lo que tengo problemas es como puedo subir un file de formato txt que lo tengo guardado en mi disco D en una carpeta llamada SENDSUNAT\doc.txt una vez que me devuelva eso, me genera un ticket al cual lo concateno y me devolverán 3 archivos xml, zip y excel que los quiero guardar en carpeta diferentes... Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
    //VARIABLES
    const string userName = "mi usuario";
    const string password = "mi clave";
    const string apiBaseUri = "https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443";
    const string apiGetPeoplePath = "/api-efact-ose/oauth";
    const string authorization = "Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==";
    const string tempurl = @"D:\\SENDSUNAT\\doc.txt";
    const string tempurl2 = "doc.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //OBTENER EL TOKEN
        var token = GetAPIToken(userName, password, apiBaseUri).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", token);

        //HACER EL LLAMADO
        var response = GetRequest(token, apiBaseUri, apiGetPeoplePath).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("response: {0}", response);

        //ESPERAR LA CLAVE
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //SETUP CLIENTE
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorization);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //SETUP LOGIN DATA
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            });

            //ENVIAR REQUEST
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/oauth/token", formContent);


            //OBTENER EL ACCESO TOKEN DEL RESPONSE BODY
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
            return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> GetRequest(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //SETUP CLIENTE
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            //var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            //cont.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream()), "file", tempurl);

            //var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            //var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempurl));
            //cont.Add(fileContent);

            //var cont = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempurl));
            //Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("D:\\SENDSUNAT\\" + tempurl2);

            //var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            //cont.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(tempurl)));

            //var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            var method = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            const string fileName = "D:\\SENDSUNAT\\doc.txt";
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
            method.Add(streamContent, "file");

            //HACER EL REQUEST
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/v1/document", method);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento te lanza error 404? ¿Has colocado breakpoints para ver las URLs a las que te estás conectado?

Comment: En el 
var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Le doy un breakpoint y me sale que en el response no logra llamar por eso me sale el error 404. La verdad que es la primera vez que hago esto.

Comment: "La verdad que es la primera vez que hago esto", esto lo explica todo. Vamos por partes, primero lo primero, en los breakpoints, coloca uno antes para que veas cuál es la URL a la que estás apuntando, hasta donde veo quieres llegar a `https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/oauth/Token` y me late que es inexistente, algo me dice que la URL a la que quieres llegar es `https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/Token`, te recomiendo que revises la documentación de la API o le consultes directamente al proveedor. Saludos

Comment: Ya me logro salir, solo era quitarle el apiBaseUri y en el Post que estaba haciendo era ponerle toda la dirección, ya me pudo devolver el token, ahora ese token tengo que concatenarlo con Bearer que sigue en el otro static string Task pero ahora tengo otro problema, no se como subir mi archivo de texto que tengo guardado en mi disco D en una carpeta

var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                cont.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream()), "file", "doc.txt");

Le estoy poniendo este código...

Comment: Coloca el código que tienes funcionando y marcas la respuesta como aceptada en 24 horas, así ayudas a más desarrolladores y mantienes la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la librería restsharp.

```
     // obtener tocken
     public string getToken(String sURL, String sUserName, String sPassword)
     {  String access_token = "";
         string clientId = "client";
         string clientSecret = "secret";
         string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret);
         RestClient restClient = new RestClient(sURL);
         RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/oauth/token");
         restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
         restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
         restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
         restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
         restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
         restRequest.AddParameter("username", sUserName);
         restRequest.AddParameter("password", sPassword);
         try {
             var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){
                 dynamic objError = new ExpandoObject();
                 objError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                 access_token = "";
                 var error = objError.invalid_grant;
                 var error_description = objError.error_description;
                 MessageBox.Show(error + " - " + error_description, "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
                 dynamic objRpta = new ExpandoObject();
                 objRpta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                 access_token = objRpta.access_token;
                 String token_type = objRpta.token_type;
                 int expires_in = objRpta.expires_in;
             }
         }
         catch(IOException e){
             MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }
         return access_token;
    }

    //send txt
    public string sendDocumentoTXT(String strAccesoToken, String strRutaDocumento, String strURL)
    {
        String strTicket = "";
        String code = "";
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(strURL);
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/v1/document");
        restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        restRequest.Method = Method.POST;

        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + strAccesoToken);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        restRequest.AddFile("file", strRutaDocumento);

        var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

        dynamic objRptaTicket = new ExpandoObject();
        objRptaTicket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){ 
            code = objRptaTicket.code;
            strTicket = objRptaTicket.description;
        }
        else{
            strEnvioDocCode = objRptaTicket.code;
            strEnvioDocTicket = objRptaTicket.description;
            MessageBox.Show(strEnvioDocCode + " " + strEnvioDocTicket, "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        return strTicket;
    }
```

Comment: Intenta explicar el porque de tu respuesta en la misma para que sepa los motivos por los cuales tiene que usar esta libreria.

Comment: Esa librería lo agrego desde mi Nuget ¿no? Como se llama exactamente esa libería restsharp, así lo busco?

Comment: Bueno yo los ando haciendo en consola de C# y ya encontré las librerías.

Comment: Para Instalar la librería: Install-Package RestSharp -Version 106.3.1 ademas usa las siguientes directivas para que no tengas errores en los métodos:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System.Collections;
using System.Dynamic;